# External folders in scrivener?

Tags: organization, scrivener

I have a couple of folders with artwork, maps etc. I would like to include this folders to my scrivener project but I don't know how.

The furthest I've got is to drag files from folder to Scrivener window. That way I can open my files, but they are all put in folder with all the other files and get renamed to a number (in scrivener project folder /files/docs).

What I want is to have an "external" folder inside my project. I want to have a folder which would be outside of the project directory but at the same time be able to view its contents and open files from scrivener.

Also any other solution that doesn't require to open the project from scrivener to change/add/remove/etc files is completely acceptable.

Note that all of this "externel" files would be images or sound files. I often work on and organize only the images and don't want to have to open scrivener every single time I want to add an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add external references to a Scrivener Project. Gwen Hernandes [describes the procedure in her blog](http://gwenhernandez.com/2013/10/23/references-in-scrivener/) (images below taken from the linked site):

Click the References button in the inspector, then click the header of the References pane to toggle between Project References and Document References:

[image]

Click the + to "Look Up & Add External Reference ..."

[image]

The files added to that folder are not added to Scrivener automatically. If you are adventurous, you could have `launchd` watch that folder for changes and trigger a Shell script that edits the relevant Scrivener project files.

Comment: Thanks. I will work out how to write that Shell script [:

Comment: Oh, if you do, please share it. I'd be interested to use it :-)

Comment: probably in a week or two when I find some time